# Post a link to my web by php

Tags: php, html, post, hyperlink

I was trying to post a link to my webpage by entering a website in the textbox:

```
網址:<input type="text" name="picwebsite" >
<input type="submit" value="送出" name="submitP">
<?php   
$bb=$_POST['picwebsite'];
if(!empty($_POST['picwebsite'])){echo <a href="$bb">"$cc"</a>;}
else{echo 'wrong<br>';}
?>
```

and the webpage shows wrong message.

After googling for help，I changed the code to:

```
{echo '<a href="'. $bb. '">'.$cc.'</a>';}
```

Now it works, but I still don't understand why

Comment: `herf` that is spelled incorrectly. And I doubt that works `echo '<a herf="'. $bb. '">'.$cc.'</a>';` no way.

Answer (score 1):

You have not quoted `a` Anchor tag use like this

```
if(!empty($_POST['picwebsite'])){
   echo "<a href='$bb'>$cc</a>";
}
```

Comment: `echo "<a herf='$bb'>$cc</a>";` will not work; there's a typo.

Comment: thanks a lot !    But why it's error if  I use " "after href =

Comment: if I need to write php in html ，then I should use ' ' instead of  " "?

Answer (score 0):

Change code to:

```
echo "<a href='$bb'>$cc</a>";
```

The problem was in wrong php syntax. You must echo `string`. In your case code was invalid besides of missing string quote declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Correct way is

```
echo '<a href="'.$bb.'">'.$cc.'</a>';
```

Or

```
echo "<a href='{$bb}'>{$cc}</a>";
```

Or

```
printf("<a href='%s'>%s</a>", $bb, $cc);
```

Or

```
<a href="<?=$bb?>"><?=$cc?></a>
```

Comment: thanks!  it really help me to learn a lot.   In the first way you write:  '<>.'$cc.'<>   do you mean '.$cc.' or .'$cc.'  ???         Beside,i still cant understand why using this type to quote$bb----->  '' '.$bb.' "

Comment: @簡庭威 oops yes I meant `'<a href="'.$bb.'">'.$cc.'</a>'`

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="POST">


網址:<input type="text" name="picwebsite" >
<input type="text" name="picwebsite" >

    <input type="submit" value="送出" name="submitP">

    <?php
    if(isset($_REQUEST['submitP'])) {
        $bb=$_POST['picwebsite'];
        if(!empty($bb))
        {
            echo '<a href='.$bb.'>'.$bb.'</a>';
        }
        else{
            echo 'wrong<br>';
        }
    } 
    ?>
```

Please check this code it will works.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! it do works. What'ii happen if i haven't add ---------
 ------->  if(isset($_REQUEST['submitP'])) {.......}

Answer (score -1):

You should use the brackets so it's easier to find your variables inside the strings and make them look cleaner.

but you can try this code too. I think you have done some syntax error.

```
if( ! empty($_POST['submitP'])){
   $bb=$_POST['picwebsite'];
    if(!empty($_POST['picwebsite'])){
        echo '<a herf="'.$bb.'">'.$cc.'</a>';
     }
    else{echo 'wrong<br>';}
}
```

Comment: `echo "<a herf='$bb'>$cc</a>";` will not work; there's a typo.

Comment: thanks a lot ! Why its error if i quote $bb with " "